# connecting two routers

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, router

I have two routers, both wireless, that I wish to connect together. As it stands Router An is connected via a micro filter into the phone line which I access the web wirelessly. 
What I want to achieve is to connect Router B to A so I can hardwire My TV and Sky (cable) Box into B and simultaneously browse the web wirelessly via router A. Is this possible?

If so I'd appreciate the help on this one to save me running 50ft cable under the carpet!

PS I'm using Mac OS.

Comment: Please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/437814/edit) your question to include the [model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_number#Model) of each router.

Answer (score 0):

If your router models are supported you can install the custom firmware from  on them and set one up as an access point and another as a client or a repeater.

Firmware: http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index

Guide to Linking : http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linking_Routers